# Images not stacking column wise within a row in bootstrap 4.0

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, bootstrap-4

I am trying to create a responsive web page using bootstrap. In the small view (xs and sm) the page works fine. I hid some images for the smaller view and it has a very standard layout.

Problem starts when I increase the screen size. In the large views (>=md) I have tried to stack four images column-wise with a row. The fourth image always goes to the next row, no matter what I do.

I have tried setting margin,padding and borders to zero but still no luck. I have attached a link to my problem in code pen. The actual html file and css are slightly bigger so I have narrowed it down only to show the problematic part. Please ignore any unused classes or ids in my code. Thanks

https://codepen.io/maheenul/pen/mLdmvy?editors=1100

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>Responsive Design Lab</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/responsive.css"/>
        <meta charset = "UTF-8">
        <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
        <link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"
        integrity="sha384-9gVQ4dYFwwWSjIDZnLEWnxCjeSWFphJiwGPXr1jddIhOegiu1FwO5qRGvFXOdJZ4" crossorigin="anonymous">

    </head>

    <body>

        <section id = "center">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-12">
                        <h2>Images not confined within the row</h2>
                        <div class="myClass">
                            <h3> Loren Ipsum</h3>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="row  d-none d-md-block">
                    <img class="col-md-3" src="https://encrypted-tbn2.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTzDojh5E0fzvTg4nWYs0JadpTwcS2S1KHOtnVQnlruNqmNvfIk" alt="Football">
                    <img class="col-md-3" src="https://encrypted-tbn1.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTO8WIJ5ygVENopHPC5Op9z4ua-MoGD-LoUZuEd6vdL-EMro28CWw" alt="Solar Car">
                    <img class="col-md-3" src="http://www-personal.umich.edu/~jensenl/visuals/album/annarbor/IMG_1051.jpg" alt="campus">
                    <img class="col-md-3" src="https://encrypted-tbn2.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTzDojh5E0fzvTg4nWYs0JadpTwcS2S1KHOtnVQnlruNqmNvfIk" alt="Football">
                </div>
            </div>

        </section>

        <footer>
            <p>The images above don't stack .<br/> Responsive Design</p>
        </footer>
    </body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
body{
    margin: 1%;
    padding:1%;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,255,.2) !important;
    font-size: 100%;
    min-width: 500px;
}

header, footer{
    background-color:#0066FF;
    padding: 1%;
    margin: 1%;
}

header h1{
    font-size: 3rem;
    color:rgba(0,0,0,.7);;
}

section{
    margin:0%;
    padding:0%;
}

.myClass{
    margin: 0em 1em;
    padding:.75em;
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-radius: .25%;
}

footer{
    clear: both;
    text-align:center;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}


@media screen and (min-width: 768px){
    header, footer{
        background-color:transparent;
    }

    img{
        display: inline-block;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        border:0; 
        overflow: auto;
    }

}
```

Comment: The easiest fix for this would be to wrap your image in a `<div class="col-md-3">...</div>` instead of applying the class directly to the image.

Comment: Tried but makes things worse. The images overflows the divs and stacks on top of one another. Thanks for your input though :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add font-size: 0; on <div class="row  d-none d-md-block">.
The spaces between images are taking space, thats why its not fitting in 1 row.

Comment: Please refer the following link

https://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/

Comment: Thank you so much! I wasted hours trying to figure this out! It works perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

The problem you're having with `row d-none d-md-block` is that the Grid in Bootstrap 4 is not a block element; it is flex.  This code changes the display method on MD+ devices from flex to block.

The correct class to use is `row d-none d-md-flex`.  When you do this you restore Bootstrap's Grid behavior; but you also cause your images to display incorrectly as you've applied the Grid directly to the image.  To fix that we have to wrap the columns around the image and then apply some responsive image behavior to the actual image element.

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-9gVQ4dYFwwWSjIDZnLEWnxCjeSWFphJiwGPXr1jddIhOegiu1FwO5qRGvFXOdJZ4" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-12">
      <h2>Images not confined within the row</h2>
      <div class="my-3 p-3 border border-secondary bg-secondary text-light">
        <h3>Loren Ipsum</h3>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
            
  <div class="row align-items-center d-none d-md-flex">
    <div class="col-md-3"><img src="https://encrypted-tbn2.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTzDojh5E0fzvTg4nWYs0JadpTwcS2S1KHOtnVQnlruNqmNvfIk" class="img-fluid img-thumbnail" alt="Football"></div>
    <div class="col-md-3"><img src="https://encrypted-tbn1.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTO8WIJ5ygVENopHPC5Op9z4ua-MoGD-LoUZuEd6vdL-EMro28CWw" class="img-fluid img-thumbnail" alt="Solar Car"></div>
    <div class="col-md-3"><img src="http://www-personal.umich.edu/~jensenl/visuals/album/annarbor/IMG_1051.jpg" class="img-fluid img-thumbnail" alt="campus"></div>
    <div class="col-md-3"><img src="https://encrypted-tbn2.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTzDojh5E0fzvTg4nWYs0JadpTwcS2S1KHOtnVQnlruNqmNvfIk" class="img-fluid img-thumbnail" alt="Football"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Note: Because we're hiding elements at the smallest breakpoint you will need to expand the snippet to see the full results.